# How to load dynamic data into google pie chart?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-api, google-visualization

I am using an ajax function to get data for rendering Google Pie chart and loading those data in javascript but some how the Pie chart is not rendering but when i hard code the AJAX output into javascript pie chart function it does render perfectly. Below is my code can any one tell me what's wrong? thank you for your help.

[image: this is what it looks like when it works]

```
<?php
$sales_data = koolajax.callback(get_asin_repo($asin,$sku));
?>
```

JS here:

```
// AJAX Output is ['POS', 'Sold This Month'],['AZN CG UK',893],['AZN JT UK',449],['AZN PT UK',1349]

        alert($sales_data);

        //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([$sales_data]);//This doesn't work

        //This Works
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['POS', 'Sold This Month'],['AZN CG UK',893],['AZN JT UK',449],['AZN PT UK',1349]]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Statistics For '+$asin
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: It would help to see the code that works -vs- the code that breaks.

Comment: well if i use var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([$sales_data]); it doesn't work  and if i use hard coded data like this var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['POS', 'Sold This Month'],['AZN CG UK',893],['AZN JT UK',449],['AZN PT UK',1349]]); it works fine

Comment: Post it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `[]` surrounding `$sales_data`?

Comment: And you're 100% positive that `$sales_data` is the same as what's hard-coded there? What is the output when both lines (the one that works, and the one that doesn't work) are written to the page?

Comment: yes because i have wrote the output in a .txt file, i have emailed my self and it is same as what i have hardcoded.

Comment: And what about when the browser receives it? Check out the code inspector (in Chrome it's F12, or you can right-click on the element you want to inspect and select *inspect element*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it Was really simple. all i need to do was get data from DB in JSON format and pass it in

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($sales_data);
```

function instead of

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([$sales_data])
```

And it works.
Thank you all for your support and time...........

Answer (score 0):

You must check the kind of variable returned from server and pack it in way that GoogleChart understands.

In your case, you requested that google.visualization.arrayToDataTable to create a DataSource instance for you. But that static method also requires that **YOU** follow this rule:

> This method takes in a 2-dimensional array and converts it to a
>   DataTable. See the
>   [Google Charts Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#assortedmethods%20Charts%20Documentation)

So make a check before calling that routine.

```
if ( $sales_data instanceof Array )
{
  var willWork = [];
  var entry;
  while ( $sales_data.length )
  {
    entry = $sales_data.shift();
    if ( !(entry instanceof Array) || entry.length < 2 )
      window.alert( 'Incorrect server return. Call support.' );
    willWork.push( entry );
  }
}
else
  window.alert( 'Incorrect server return. Call support.' );
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Google pie chart get data from PHP

I have been searching since 4 hours how to populate data from PHP to google pie chart but not found any solution, actually, my data format was wrong in PHP.
You can prepare data in PHP using this way:

```
function yourFunction(){
    $data = array();
    $data[0] = array("Status", "Revenue");
    $data[1] = array('Pending', 500);
    $data[2] = array('Confirmed', 1000);
    $data[3] = array('Payable', 3000);
    return json_encode($data );
}
```

Parse data on frontend:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```